# RegEx that keeps the first 3 characters and deletes the rest

Tags: regex, regular-language

I have an identifier that contains letters or digits and dashes. 
What I would like to do is to keep the first 3 letters before the first dash and delete the rest and then keep the 2 first letters after the first dash.

For instance, I have the following id :

```
9D3236A9-B496-4597-87E4-3A3FB69D07BF
```

The output ID should be : `9D3B445873A3`.

I have tried:

```
^.{3}\-
```

but nothing happens. Can you please help with that?

Comment: You're keeping three letters `3A3` in latest part. Is that part of your desire output?

Comment: It might look like [this](https://regex101.com/r/IkiOer/1). Or like [this](https://regex101.com/r/IkiOer/3). Or [this](https://regex101.com/r/IkiOer/4). Well, your (without the dashes) comment is not clear. If you need `9D3B445873A3`, just state you need this output.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Great answer. I need exactly the regex you gave me but the output should not have any dashes. It should be exactly what you mention in your last line. (9D3B445873A3) Do you think you can provide a regex for that too?

Comment: So, use https://regex101.com/r/IkiOer/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^([A-Za-z0-9]{3})[A-Za-z0-9]*|-([A-Za-z0-9]{3})[A-Za-z0-9]*$|-([A-Za-z0-9]{2})[A-Za-z0-9]*
```

Replace with `$1$2$3`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IkiOer/4/).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string

  - `([A-Za-z0-9]{3})` - Group 1 (`$1` in the replacement): 3 alphanumeric chars
  - `[A-Za-z0-9]*` - 0+ alphanumerics
- `|` - or

  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `([A-Za-z0-9]{3})`  - Group 2 (`$2` in the replacement): 3 alphanumeric chars
  - `[A-Za-z0-9]*` - 0+ alphanumerics
  - `$` - end of string
- `|`

  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `([A-Za-z0-9]{2})` - Group 3 (`$3` in the replacement): 2 alphanumeric chars
  - `[A-Za-z0-9]*` - 0+ alphanumerics.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex given in this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hmopdB/1)

```
(^.{3})[a-z0-9A-Z]*((?>-).{2})[a-z0-9A-Z]*((?>-).{2})[a-z0-9A-Z]*((?>-).{2})[a-z0-9A-Z]*((?>-).{2})[a-zA-Z0-9]*
```